# Flex - Datagrid ItemRenderer

Tags: apache-flex, itemrenderer

Is it possible to put an itemrenderer on the DataGrid itself rather than a datagridcolumn? I could only find examples for datagridcolumn.
I want a generic itemrenderer on all the items in a datagrid...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. (this is a Flex 4 example, but same is true for 3)

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/halo" minWidth="1024" minHeight="768">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            [Bindable] private var dp:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([{far:"test",sight:"test"},{far:"test",sight:"test"},{far:"test",sight:"test"},{far:"test",sight:"test"}]);
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <mx:DataGrid width="100%" height="100%" dataProvider="{dp}">
        <mx:itemRenderer>
            <fx:Component>
                <mx:Label text="woot there it is"/>
            </fx:Component>
        </mx:itemRenderer>
    </mx:DataGrid>
</s:Application>
```

[Peter Ent's itemRenderer Series is killer.](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/itemrenderers_pt1.html)